# Tapestry and Underscore incompatibility

Tags: underscore.js, tapestry

I am trying to use some of Underscore's methods in a Tapestry project, but have ran into an issue that I don't see how to solve.

Trying to use code with the following format:

```
<% if (0 > 1) { %>
    <div>You can't see me</div>
<% } %>
<% if (0 < 1) { %>
    <div>You can see me</div>
<% } %>
```

Will result in the following error:

> Failure parsing template classpath:my/template/path/mytemplate.tml:
>   Unexpected character '%' (code 37) in content after '<' (malformed
>   start element?). at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [70,10]

I understand Tapestry is a bit "strict" (understatement of the year) about its parsing, but is there a workaround, or is Underscore just not usable with Tapestry?

Comment: Don't know anything about Tapestry but have you tried using [`_.templateSettings`](http://underscorejs.org/#template) to use different delimiters in your Underscore templates?

Comment: @muistooshort Ah, didn't know that was a possibility! I will try that, thanks.